# To get data from rows based on row conditions in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in the following structure:

[image: Table of my data]

I would like to only get tag y which is between tag x with value bigger than 4 and smaller than 8:

[image: Result]

Any recommendations of functions that might make my case?

Thx in advanced

Comment: What would happen if value `15` also have a `tag` of `'x'`?

Comment: `where value > 4 and value < 8`.

Comment: The thing is that the table shown above is just an simplification of my table output. The real table contains x and y that is very different. Ideally I would like to get the date of tag x where value is 4 and value is 8 and then make a statement where I can say something like: date between my_first_found_value and my_second_found_value.

Comment: So 4 and 8 is fixed or do you want all y's that are wrapped between x?

Comment: All that which is wrapped between x:)

Comment: Do a search on islands and gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME;

SELECT @StartDate = t.[date]
FROM dbo.MyTable t
WHERE t.tag = 'x'
AND t.value = 4;

SELECT @EndDate = t.[date]
FROM dbo.MyTable t
WHERE t.tag = 'x'
AND t.value = 8;

SELECT
  t.[date]
  ,t.tag
  ,t.value
FROM dbo.MyTable t
WHERE t.tag = 'y'
AND t.[date] > @StartDate
AND t.[date] < @EndDate
ORDER BY t.[date];
```

OR (if you absolutely must have it in a single query)

```
SELECT
  t.[date]
  ,t.tag
  ,t.value
FROM dbo.MyTable t
WHERE t.tag = 'y'
AND t.[date] > (SELECT t2.[date] FROM dbo.MyTable t2 WHERE t2.tag = 'x' AND t2.value = 4)
AND t.[date] < (SELECT t3.[date] FROM dbo.MyTable t3 WHERE t3.tag = 'x' AND t3.value = 8)
ORDER BY t.[date];
```

Comment: Great!:) thanks alot - just what i needed!:D I have upvoted but it is not shown as I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: No problem.  You need to select this as the answer instead of upvoting.  Thanks!